# Estimating the probability that $\|Av\| \ge \|v\|$

Tags: reference-request, random-matrices, norms

Given a diagonalizable matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ with real eigenvalues, satisfying $1+c_1 \le \rho(A) \le 1+c_2$ $(0<c_1 \le c_2)$, obviously there exists a $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\|Av\| \ge \|v\|$.

I am interested in the case where $v$ is drawn uniformly at random from some discrete distribution, for instance $\{\pm1\}^{n}$. Are there any known lower bounds on $\Pr[\|Av\| \ge \|v\|]$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have very few vectors in the discrete set satisfy the bound.  For example, let $A$ be the matrix with zeros everywhere except for $1+c_1$ in the upper left corner (let's assume $1+c_1<\sqrt{2}$).  Then there are only two vectors in $\{\pm 1\}^n$ which satisfy $\Vert Av\Vert \geq \Vert v\Vert$.

It follows that the lower bound question is roughly equivalent to asking whether there must be *any* vector in $\{\pm 1\}^n$ satisfying the bound.